# AWQL / Apps Script WHERE Date Day Name Equals Today's Day Name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm running a basic AWQL and apps script query from my account to a google sheet. I currently have a similar script for just today working on a trend basis. I'm building an automated report selecting campaign performance for the last 30 days. However, due to the size of the account I only want to select the days in that time frame which match today's day name. e.g. today is Friday, so I only want the data for the Friday's in the date range. This is a trended data report which is why I only want the current day of week.

Below is an example of the code to push into a spreadsheet. I can never get this to run with a WHERE statement included. I have tried many variations which had led me to this question.

I receive the "Parsing error. Please check your selector." error message which is due to the where statement but i'm struggling to understand why.

```
   function main(){

    var sheetURL = 'INSERT_SPREADSHEET_URL_HERE';
    var sheetName = 'googleData';

    //This is the days of the week for the today lookup
    var days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday' ];

    //This is today's date
    var end = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);

    //This is for x amount of days previous, currently set at 30 days
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate()-30);
    var start = d.toISOString().slice(0,10);

    //This joins the two above dates together and replaces / with blank characters
    var dateRanges = start.replace(/-/g,"") + "," + end.replace(/-/g,"");

    //This supplies the current day of week
    var dow = new Date(end);
    var dayName = days[dow.getDay()];

    //Check the correct day of week is showing
    //Logger.log(dayName);

    //This is to check the date format is correct
    //Logger.log(dateRanges);

    var QUERIES = [{'query' : 'SELECT Date, DayOfWeek, HourOfDay, CampaignName, Impressions, Clicks, Cost, Conversions, ConversionValue ' +
                'FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' +
                'WHERE DayOfWeek = ' + dayName +
                'DURING ' + dateRanges, 
                'spreadsheetUrl' : + sheetURL,
                'tabName' : 'googleData',
                'reportVersion' : 'v201806'
               }            
              ];


      //This is to gather the above query and push it to the spreadsheet stated above
     for(var i in QUERIES) {
        var queryObject = QUERIES[i];
        var query = queryObject.query;
        var spreadsheetUrl = queryObject.spreadsheetUrl;
        var tabName = queryObject.tabName;
        var reportVersion = queryObject.reportVersion;
        //Logger.log(spreadsheetUrl + " " + query);
        var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl);
        var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(tabName);
        var report = AdWordsApp.report(query, {apiVersion: reportVersion});
        report.exportToSheet(sheet);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `WHERE` clause, the `dayName` value should probably be surrounded in quotes.

Try this (note I used single quotes instead of double quotes):

```
var query = "SELECT Date, DayOfWeek, HourOfDay, CampaignName, Impressions, Clicks, Cost, Conversions, ConversionValue "
        + "FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT" 
        + "WHERE DayOfWeek = '" + dayName + "'"
        + "DURING " + dateRanges;

var QUERIES = [{
        query:query, 
        spreadsheetUrl: sheetURL, 
        tabName:"googleData", 
        reportVersion:"v201806"
    }];
```

**TIP**: In future, consider using [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) instead of slicing up date strings or using a look up table for days.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean like this - 'WHERE DayOfWeek = ' + "'" + dayName + "'" +. If so then it brings the same result unfortunately.

Comment: Huge thank you for the updated post and help on this. The slice is at 10 due to the "\". In the dateRanges variable I then have a replace from "\" to "" which gives the correct date format as I have used it on other scripts. I have just tried out the new section and receiving the same parsing error message. It looks like it isn't enjoying the where statement. if i changed it to say impressions > 10 then it works. Thanks for the tip as well, I'll check that out.

Comment: Thank you for the help so far. Over the weekend I thought of the possibility to add a while loop which would go through an array of dates. While there were dates which equalled today's day name then run query. However, my knowledge of javascript is very basic at the moment (seen by the above code) so any insight whether this is possible would be great. Thanks, Liam